# Tradingview lightweight-charts: How to increase number after point?

Tags: lightweight-charts

I noticed that the price is not displayed correctly.
I set 0.123456 but see on chart just 0.12
Please give me some advices.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Copied from https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/discussions/697#discussioncomment-348803:

To change format of your series' data you need to override [price format](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/blob/master/docs/series-basics.md#price-format) for your series by changing/applying options.

For example, if you'd like to show 6 digits after a comma you can use the following options:

```js
series.applyOptions({
    priceFormat: {
        type: 'price',
        precision: 6,
        minMove: 0.000001,
    },
});
```